# What are the Lost Logia?

Tags: nanoha

In *Magical Girl Lyrical Nanoha* Season 1, Yuuno says that the Lost Logia are remnants of advance civilizations that have since been destroyed, but in Season 3 during Hayate and Fate's briefing on the relic they seem to imply that the Lost Logia come from a single civilization (Al Hazard maybe?)

So I am wondering, what exactly are the Lost Logia?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A *Lost Logia* is a piece of technology from an ancient world.

We have seen *Lost Logia* from *Ancient Belka* (Book of Darkness, Bible of Silver Cross) and *Al Hazard* (Jewel Seed, Relic, Saints Cradle).

Nanoha lives in *Mid-Childa*, and for them *Ancient Belka* is a lost world. For the inhabitants of *Ancient Belka* during the *Belkan War*, *Al Hazard* was a lost world to them as well. Due to the *Belkan War* you can see a lot of influences from *Al Hazard* as they tried to harness the immeasurable power of the *Lost Logia* of *Al Hazard*.

On the collapse of *Ancient Belka*, they tried to rebuild their empire using the *Al Hazard Lost Logia*, the *Saint's Cradle*. That was the *Saint King Unification War* with the lovable *Olivie Sägebrecht*. So that is a bit of history of the *Lost Logia*, a technology which has been lost.

Remember the 'magic' that Nanoha uses is technology as well, except that it is not mass-based (like a Nuclear Bomb), but magic-based (an energy coming from living beings, apparently) and was chosen technology for the *Time Space Administration* due to it being clean and relatively safe.